# 'cannot find symbol variable' in android data binding include layout

Tags: android, data-binding

*layout_content.xml*

```
<layout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:id="@+id/appbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</layout>
```

*layout_main.xml*

```
<layout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/dl_main_drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

       <include layout="@layout/layout_content" android:id="@+id/content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
LayoutMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.layout_main);
setSupportActionBar(binding.content.toolbar);
```

Android Studio intellisense check binding.content is ViewDataBinding obj

but build error 'cannot find symbol variable content'
Will this have any problem?
thx!

Comment: Is this with rc1 or rc0?

Comment: I use rc1. and gradle is 1.3.0-beta4

Comment: This happens when you've renamed a layout file and the old generated Binding class is still hanging around. Try choosing "Build->Clean Project" and then recompile.

Comment: I try Clean Project and recompile,but not work. I try reopen Android studio,Also not work.

Comment: And i try create new project,but build still show 'cannot find symbol variable content' error

Comment: I tested the code you have and it compiled fine for me. The error normally comes from the generated code. Android Studio will go to the place where the error is. Can you edit your question and add the code (+/- ~20 lines) that is generating the error and indicate which line is generating the error? Also, if the error isn't coming from LayoutContentBinding.java or LayoutMainBinding.java, please add the layout that is related to the binding as well. You can also file a bug in the bug tracker and post your project there.

Comment: I upload my test project in [gitHub](https://github.com/tatsuyuki25/AndroidTestDataBinding)

Comment: I have no idea this code where wrong

Comment: Android studio show error is '...\testdatabinding\MainActivity.java Error:(17, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable content'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The layout `activity_main.xml`:

```
<layout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_content" android:id="@+id/content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

generates `ActivityMainBinding.java`. In your MainActivity.java, you use the generated field for `content` in the `setSupportActionBar` argument:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
    setSupportActionBar(binding.content.toolbar);
}
```

Normally a layout will generate public final fields for each of the Views with `android:id`s and Binding subclasses for each of the includes with IDs. In this case, the data binding system did not detect that the included content `@layout/layout_content` was a binding layout and thus didn't capture the Binding class for the include.

When a variable is bound to an include, the data binding system will use that to determine that the included layout is a binding layout. So, if your layout had this instead:

```
<include layout="@layout/layout_content"
         android:id="@+id/content"
         app:someVar="@{someVar}" />
```

You'd have gotten a content field with the type `LayoutContentBinding`. This does assume that `someVar` is declared in both `activity_main.xml` and `layout_content.xml`.

The error in Android Studio was pointing to the correct location, but it was difficult to understand. In the future, you can look for the generated binding class in your `app/build` directory. This may help you figure out what the error means.

I've filed a bug to fix the error -- we should be generating a public final field for the include with the ID.

Comment: Now is work,but i think this is not great solution.I hope next update `<include layout="@layout/layout_content" android:id="@+id/content" />` is work.Thank you.

Comment: I reported to issue tracker here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186914. Hope it will solve in near future, and they don't delete my that issue.

Comment: It is solved as of rc2, which went out this week. Enjoy!