# How to implement toolbar with viewbinding in fragment?

Tags: android

I would like to implement a toolbar in the fragment.
I am using binding to use elements from .xml.
I implement in Kotlin, android studio.

I have seen:
[Unable to show toolbar while using databinding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778918/unable-to-show-toolbar-while-using-databinding-in-android)
and many other articles, documentation as well, but everywhere I cannot find the proper implementation with binding.

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/teal_700"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

in fragment.xml

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

fragment.kt

Here I have tried many different implementations.
The main issue is when I make it with documentation and instead of define toolbar using findById I define it by binding.toolbar where misstype appears where it wants toolbar? not binding toolbar.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
// doesn't work setConentView and setSupportACtionBar on Red
        binding = FragmentItemSecondBinding.setContentView(this, R.layout.fragment_item_second)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        binding.setProduct(product);

        binding = FragmentItemSecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        return binding.root
    }
```

In documentation and other videos it should work when I make code like below, but setSupportActionBar doesn't exist.

```
        val toolbar = binding.toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

What is difference between:

androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
and
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

I use the first one.
My goal is to have two buttons in toolbar to have possibility to back to previous fragment + onClickSecondButton make some action.

EDIT:
TO Nukhoca

[image]

Comment: It's usually better to just keep the Toolbar in the activity rather than the fragment.  Also have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189198/how-to-use-setsupportactionbar-in-fragment

Comment: I have seen sth similar, but the problem is:
Required:
Toolbar?
Found:
ToolbarBinding

Answer (score 0):

If you import external layout using `<include />` tag, you need to set its own binding, as well. Change your code by;

```
  private lateinit binding: FragmentItemSecondBinding
  private lateinit toolbarBinding: ToolbarBinding

  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentItemSecondBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        toolbarBinding = ToolbarBinding.bind(binding.toolbar)
        (requireActivity() as YourActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbarBinding.toolbar) // in toolbar.xml set an ID to your component e.g. toolbar
        binding.setProduct(product);

        return binding.root
    }
```

Of course, I tried to keep code as short as possible. You should make your bindings nullable and dispose them in `onDestroyView` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: check my edit, this method doesn't work in fragment it works only in mainactivity I would like to cast it in fragment, is it possible/?

Comment: @chrisu.chrisu just do below

`(requireActivity() as YourActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbarBinding.toolbar)`

or

`(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbarBinding.toolbar)`

Comment: @chrisu.chrisu Did it work? If so can mark my comment as answer?

Comment: I had the other implementations to do and make it just by id. I will check it and write in 2-3 days for sure.

greetings